# SVG blend-mode "screen" formula

Tags: html, css, svg, graphics, formula

So I want to learn about one of blend mode "screen",but when I search for formula,this is what I get

```
B(Cb, Cs) = 1 - [(1 - Cb) x (1 - Cs)]
```

(
https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/blending-modes-in-css-color-theory-and-practical-application--cms-25201t
)
`

**B** refers to the blending function.

**Cb** variable is the background color.

**Cs** variable is the source color.`

My test was:

First element(that's have the code):

**rgba(0,120,0,1)**

Second element:

**rgba(0,120,0,1)**

But when I calculated,I try the **green** first:

```
B(Cb, Cs) = 1 - [(1 - (120÷255)) x (1 - (120÷255))]
```

My result( **183** ) is not the same as I was tested in website test,

my result in my web is:

the green color value=about **158**

Which is not near to my calculation ( **183** )

Comment: the result is 183, if you see a different color check your setting. sometimes you can find configuration that adjust the color slightly like the color profile

Comment: Did you account for the colour space I.e. this conversion is likely happening in the linearRGB colour space?